# Split text with {{Text}} format Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Sorry to bother you all. I'm no idea about regular expression. But right now I need one very badly.
I want to split text using this format {{Text}}. The "Text" can be anything. All I need is split the text at the position of {{Text}}.

Here is a sample.

```
var Regx = My Regx;
var String = "{{This}} is a {{test}} string to be {{spliced}} with {{Regular}} Expression";

var SplitArray = String.split(Regx);
// it will give me an array like this
// ["","is a ","string to be "," with"," Expression"]
```

Thank you in advance.

**Edit:**
I solved it myself too. It is `{{[^{}]+}}`

Comment: Your expected output is whitespace-inconsistent. Please check if there should be whitespace in the 2nd, 3rd and 4th items.

Comment: It could be.No problem.But in the parameter it can be like this also {{space space}} or {{space-space}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var Regx = /\{\{.*?\}\}/;
var String = "{{This}} is a {{test}} string to be {{spliced}} with {{Regular}} Expression";

var SplitArray = String.split(Regx);
console.log(SplitArray);
// it will give me an array like this
// ["","is a ","string to be "," with"," Expression"]
```

Comment: Sorry at the same time, you go ahead

Comment: :) Let the OP decide!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way

```
var test = "{{This}} is a {{test}} string to be {{spliced}} with {{Regular}} Expression";
var SplitArray = test.split(/\{\{.*?\}\}/);

console.log(SplitArray)
```

Comment: Your code does work out too. But sideroxylon answered first. So ...
Thanks a lot.

Comment: @RazinAbid yes you are right, he is 40 secs before me